# Reading values from Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three pages in my `viewpager`, each page is a `fragment`, And I have some `EditText`'s in each page, I third page I have a `Button` called **SAVE**, Now in this button click event I have to the values from all `EditText`'s. I have tried many way, but none is worked, Always I am getting `NullPinterException`. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Guna.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar set up in my current app. What I did was create a subclass of Fragment that has the method:

```
public abstract String[] getForm();
```

the getForm method essentially returns a String[] containing the string stored in each form. Each Fragment has to implement that correctly. Now once you have that, in your Activity that contains the ViewPager initialize a list of fragments that your activity's ViewPagerAdapter should use to display. That way, now when you are in the final fragment and this button is clicked (and your fragment that contains the button click successfully informs the activity that the button click event occurred), your activity will know to iterate through the whole list of fragments, calling the fragments respective getForm method implementation.

Note that this will only work if you are not using a ViewStatePagerAdapter. The reason for this is because the ViewStatePagerAdapter is not guaranteed to keep all of your fragments in memory.

Here is a code example (In the code example, I have my view pager stored in a fragment but this design would most definitely work if you were keeping your viewpager in an activity). The real work is being done in the submit method. That is where we are collecting the fields from the other fragment (Hence this method should be called in you OnButtonClickListener code):

```
public class CreateAccountFragment extends RestCallExecutingFragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private OnAccountCreationListener onAccountCreationListener;
    public static final int VARIOUS_FRAG_POS = 2;
    public static final int ACCOUNT_INFO_FRAG_POS = 0;
    private static final int ADDRESS_FRAG_POS = 1;
    public static final int CREATE_ACCOUNT_ID = 0;

    public CreateAccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    ArrayList<FormFragment> fragmentsToDisplay;

  /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @InjectView(R.id.rb_accountInfo)
    RadioButton rb_accountInfo;

    @InjectView(R.id.rb_address)
    RadioButton rb_address;

    @InjectView(R.id.rb_various)
    RadioButton rb_various;

    @InjectView(R.id.rg_createAccount)
    RadioGroup rg_createAccount;

    @InjectView(R.id.tv_pageTitle)
    TextView tv_pageTitle;

    List<RadioButton> radioButtons;

    CreateAccountCommand createAccountCommand;

    private static ArrayList<FormFragment> getCreateAccountFragments(){
        ArrayList<FormFragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(AccountInfoFragment.newInstance());
        list.add(AddressFragment.newInstance());
        list.add(VariousFragment.newInstance());
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_create_account, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        fragmentsToDisplay = getCreateAccountFragments();
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        //todo make it easier to press the radio button
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public void submit() {
        //todo move the create account button to this activity's view
        AccountSubmissionRDTO createAccountSubmissionDTO;
        try {
            AccountInfoData accountInfoData =  (AccountInfoData) fragmentsToDisplay.get(ACCOUNT_INFO_FRAG_POS).submitForm();
            AddressData addressData = (AddressData) fragmentsToDisplay.get(ADDRESS_FRAG_POS).submitForm();
            VariousData variousData = (VariousData) fragmentsToDisplay.get(VARIOUS_FRAG_POS).submitForm();
          //  createAccountSubmissionDTO = new CreateAccountSubmissionRDTO(CREATE_ACCOUNT_ID,0, -1, accountInfoData,addressData,variousData); //todo create actual server and local ids

    }

    /**
     * A {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            FormFragment selectedFragment = fragmentsToDisplay.get(position);

            Assert.assertNotNull("the fragment selected should be within list", selectedFragment);
            return selectedFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentsToDisplay.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            String pageTitle = fragmentsToDisplay.get(position).getPageTitle();
            return pageTitle.toUpperCase(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gunaseelan I added the code example. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help...

Comment: May I know where you initialize `rb_accountInfo` and where you access its value.

Comment: I use Butterknife (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to inject my views. However, you can ignore that for what I was trying to show you. (I copied this code from my company's private repo and tried to do my best of removing all the code that wasn't related to your question) the same goes for rb_accountInfo. It is used elsewhere in the code but I removed it since i didn't want to add too much code that wasn't related to what I was trying to show you. You can ignore all of the code. That doesn't have anything to do with either the submit button or the viewpager.

Comment: You should ignore anything that doesn't have to do with either the submit method or the viewpager. Let me know if this helps...